# Restoring 'Main.storyboard' toolbar in Xmarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I accidentally closed down the toolbox items on the sidebar by clicking the 'x' and now I can't seem to find where in the settings to get them back
Any ideas?

Sidebar on right is missing.
[image: <code>Main.stroryboard</code> missing toolbar at side]

Sidebar with tools present with this file, as an example of what I should be seeing on the right hand side in the first picture.
[image: <code>MainViewController</code> with its sidebar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the main menu

```
View --> Pads --> Properties
```

Comment: Perfect. Cheers mate